# Cloning Pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, clone

This question is regarding copying and pointer polymorphism. Consider the code below. We have two classes: **Base** and **Derived**, which are just regular objects. Then we've got class **Foo**, which has a pointer to **Base** as its only member.

The typical usage of **Foo** is described in the `main` function. The input to `Foo::SetMemberX` may or may not be a temporary object.

The problem is that I want `Foo::SetMember` to create a proper copy of the passed object, and assign its address as a `Base*` to `Foo::mMember`.

I've managed to come up with 4 possible solution, none of which seem very elegant to me. The first three are shown in the code below in `Foo::SetMember1`, `Foo::SetMember2`, and `Foo::SetMember3`. The 4th option is to leave the memory allocation to the user (ex. `foo.SetMember(new Derived())`), which is not very desirable for obvious memory safety issues. **Foo** should be responsible for memory management, not the user.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename tBase, typename tPointer>
void ClonePointer(tBase*& destination, const tPointer* pointer)
{
    destination = static_cast<tBase*>(new tPointer(*pointer));
}

// Base can be a virtual class
class Base
{
public:

    virtual void Function()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Function()" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual Base* Clone() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void Function()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::Function()" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual Base* Clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo() : mMember(NULL) { }

    ~Foo()
    {
        if (mMember != NULL)
        {
            delete mMember;
            mMember = NULL;
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    void SetMember1(const T& t)
    {
        if (mMember != NULL)
        {
            delete mMember;
            mMember = NULL;
        }

        ClonePointer(mMember, &t);
    }

    void SetMember2(const Base& b)
    {
        mMember = b.Clone();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void SetMember3(const T& t)
    {
        if (mMember != NULL)
        {
            delete mMember;
            mMember = NULL;
        }

        mMember = new T(t);
    }

    Base& GetMember()
    {
        return *mMember;
    }

private:

    Base* mMember;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    {
        Foo f1;
        Foo f2;
        Foo f3;

        // The input may or may not be a tempoary/RValue reference

        f1.SetMember1(Derived());
        f2.SetMember2(Derived());
        f3.SetMember3(Derived());

        f1.GetMember().Function();
        f2.GetMember().Function();
        f3.GetMember().Function();
    }

    // Output:
    // Derived::Function();
    // Derived::Function();
    // Derived::Function();

    system("pause"); // for quick testing
}
```

The problem with the first method (`Foo::SetMember1`) is that I have a random, free, template function, and a template accessore (see the problem with the third method below).

The problem with the second method (`Foo::SetMember2`) is that every derived class must implement its own `Clone` function. This is too much boilerplate code for the class user, as there will be a lot of classes deriving from **Base**. If I could somehow automate this, or create a base **Cloneable** class (without each **Base**-derived class having to explicitly calling it) with an implemented template `Clone` function, this would be the ideal solution.

The problem with the third method (`Foo::SetMember3`) is that I'd need a template accessor for **Foo**. This may not always be possible, especially because of how virtual template methods are not allowed in non-template classes (**Foo** cannot be a template itself), which is a functionality that might be required.

My questions are:

1. Are these the only options I have?
2. Is there a better, more elegant solution to this problem that I'm missing?
3. Is there any way to create a base **Cloneable** class and derive **Base** from it, and have cloning automagically happen for `DerivedType::Clone()`?

Comment: Pro tip: if you think you need to write `delete` in a destructor make a class *just for that*, also known as smart pointer. I use this: https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/default/include/wheels/smart_ptr/value_ptr.h++

Comment: If I recall my Polymorphism right, option 2 is the one for you. Or at least a variation of it. Declare a public 'Clone' function, which is to be called from the user code. Then declare an abstract Clone function, which HAS to be implemented by each subclass. The public clone function does it's own 'Cloning work' (getting called first on all occasions) and then passes the ball to the subclass, that can do their stuff...the parent class can never know, what 'cloning' the subclass has to do.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: `Foo` appears to be such a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2nd method, you can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and you won't need to write clone method in every derived class:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual Base *clone() const = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
struct CloneableBase : public Base {
  virtual Base *clone() const {
    return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this));
  }
};

struct Derived: CloneableBase<Derived> {};
```

Comment: What if a `Grandchild` class inherits from `Derived`?

Comment: In the actual design, it is assumed that no `Grandchild` inherits from `Derived`. The original design is that there is a single `Base` class, from which many classes directly inherit from, which are all "final" by protocol. So I think this solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @n.m.: change the first line to `template <typename Derived, class Base>` and `struct Derived: ClonableBase<Derived,Base>`  problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more or less robust `Clonable` class that can be inherited to any depth. It uses CRTP and Alecsandrescu-style interleaving inheritance pattern.

```
#include <iostream>

// set up a little named template parameters rig
template <class X> struct Parent{};
template <class X> struct Self{};
template<class A, class B> struct ParentChild;

// can use ...< Parent<X>, Self<Y> >...
template<class A, class B> struct ParentChild< Parent<A>, Self<B> >
{
    typedef A parent_type;
    typedef B child_type;
};

// or ...< Self<Y>, Parent<X> >
template<class A, class B> struct ParentChild< Self<B>, Parent<A> >
{
    typedef A parent_type;
    typedef B child_type;
};

// nothing, really
struct Nada
{
    // except the virtual dtor! Everything clonable will inherit from here.
    virtual ~Nada() {}
};

// The Clonable template. Accepts two parameters: 
// the child class (as in CRTP), and the parent class (one to inherit from)
// In any order.
template <class A, class B = Parent<Nada> > class Clonable : 
    public ParentChild<A,B>::parent_type
{
  public:
    // a nice name to refer to in the child class, instead of Clonable<A,B>
    typedef Clonable Parent;

    // this is our child class
    typedef typename ParentChild<A,B>::child_type child_type;

    // This is the clone() function returning the cloned object
    // Non-virtual, because the compiler has trouble with covariant return
    // type here. We have to implemens something similar, by having non-virtual
    // that returns the covariant type calling virtual that returns the 
    // base type, and some cast.
    child_type* clone()
    {
        return static_cast<child_type*>(private_clone());
    }

    // forward some constructor, C++11 style
    template<typename... Args> Clonable(Args&&... args): 
        ParentChild<A,B>::parent_type(args...) {}

  private:

    // this is the main virtual clone function
    // allocates the new child_type object and copies itself
    // with the copy constructor
    virtual Nada* private_clone() 
    {
        // we *know* we're the child_type object
        child_type* me = static_cast<child_type*>(this);
        return new child_type(*me);
    };
};

// Test drive and usage example

class Foo : public Clonable < Self<Foo> >
{
  public: 
    Foo (int) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(int)\n"; }
    Foo (double, char) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(double, char)\n"; }
    Foo (const Foo&) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(Foo&)\n"; }
};

class Bar : public Clonable < Self<Bar>, Parent<Foo> >
{
  public:
    // cannot say Bar (int i) : Foo(i), unfortunately, because Foo is not
    // our immediate parent
    // have to use the Parent alias 
    Bar (int i) : Parent(i) 
        { std::cout << "Bar::Bar(int)\n"; }
    Bar (double a, char b) : Parent(a, b) 
        { std::cout << "Bar::Bar(double, char)\n"; }
    Bar (const Bar& b) : Parent(b) 
        { std::cout << "Bar::Bar(Bar&)\n"; }

    ~Bar() { std::cout << "Bar::~Bar()\n"; }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo* foo1 = new Bar (123);
    Foo* foo2 = foo1->clone(); // this is really a Bar
    delete foo1;
    delete foo2;
}
```

Comment: While this is a very clever solution, I think Leonid's solution would be preferred for its simplicity. I really like this design pattern, though. Thanks for sharing!